# Creating a profit & loss report

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function `profit_report :: [String] -> [Transaction] -> String` that takes a list of stocks and a transaction log, and returns the human-readable string containing the profit and loss report.

Specifically, for each stock in the input list, the report should include the line `STOCK: PROFIT` where `STOCK` is the name of the stock, and `PROFIT` is the amount of profit made. The stocks should appear in the order in which they are listed in the input.

For example: the function can be tested using `putStr` like so:

```
ghci> putStr (profit_report ["VTI", "ONEQ", "IWRD"] test_log)
VTI: 14450
ONEQ: -800
IWRD: -1900
```

Here is some background information.

The transaction log looks like this:

```
test_log :: [Transaction]
test_log = [('B', 100, 1104,  "VTI",  1),
            ('B', 200,   36, "ONEQ",  3),
            ('B',  50, 1223,  "VTI",  5),
            ('S', 150, 1240,  "VTI",  9),
            ('B', 100,  229, "IWRD", 10),
            ('S', 200,   32, "ONEQ", 11), 
            ('S', 100,  210, "IWRD", 12)
            ]
```

Comment: "Here is some background information." - Where?

Answer (score 0):

You have the type declaration

```hs
profit_report :: [String] -> [Transaction] -> String
```

meaning your function takes 2 arguments.

But here you only match one:

```hs
profit_report [] = []
--            ^^
profit_report (x:xs) = x : get_trades x (x:xs) : profit(x xs)
--            ^^^^^^
```

You're missing a 2nd argument in both cases

Comment: With that removed how do I resolve the type error for the second element profit (x xs)